# Create a action in Sylpheed to decrypt messages

Tags: shell-script, email

If you like to decrypt messages in the Sylpheed email client the [manual](http://sylpheed.sraoss.jp/doc/manual/en/sylpheed-13.html) suggest to create a custom action to execute the following command:

```
*gpg2 --no-tty --batch --yes --command-fd 0 --passphrase-fd 0 --decrypt %f|
```

If I try to decrypt a email with this action the output from the terminal is written to the body of the email. But it writes only the last 1000 lines to the email file. I changed the scrollback property for the lxterminal under `/home/ubuntu/.config/lxterminal/lxterminal.conf`. But it seems it doesn't affect the output. I also tried to redirect the output to the email file at self

```
*gpg2 --no-tty --batch --yes --command-fd 0 --passphrase-fd 0 --output %f --decrypt %f
```

In this case I lost all the header information from the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a new action under `Configuration / Actions...` and assign the command `*/home/ubuntu/Documents/CustomScripts/decryptMail.sh %f ~/doc` to this action.

The decryptMail.sh file contains the following commands:

```
gpg2 --no-tty --batch --yes --command-fd 0 --passphrase-fd 0 --output $2 --decrypt $1
decryptedString=$(cat $2);
escaped=$(printf '%s\n' "$decryptedString" | sed 's:[\/&]:\\&:g;$!s/$/\\/');
sed -i '/-BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-/,/-END PGP MESSAGE-/{//!d}' $1;
sed -i "/BEGIN PGP MESSAGE/a $escaped" $1;
```

During my research two questions came up which could enhance the script. First question is about the part, when I want to insert the decrypted text from the `~/doc` file (represented by $2) into the email file (represented by $1). I read that could be done with the `r`-function but all my trails like `sed '/-BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-/r$1' $2` didn't work. Any suggestions? The second question is; how to tell `Sylpheed` to reload the email file? Till now I have to click on some other email and then back to my decrypted email to see the changes the script has done to the email file.